# Is iMessage open source?

Tags: messages, encryption, sms, open-source

My Google searches didn't turn up very many results on the subject. If it is open source, can someone link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [iMessage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMessage) is not open source.

## Proprietary Software

iMessage is proprietary software owned and operated by Apple. iMessage operates exclusively on Apple devices.